# Keepalive best practices for Nginx-Haproxy-Apache chain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, haproxy, keepalive

I am using Nginx to serve static content, and Haproxy to proxy requests to multiple Apache2 backends discovered via Zookeeper.

**Nginx -> Haproxy -> Apache2**

According to the official Nginx website, it aggregates long-keepalive connections on their way to back ends like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLvAT.png), reducing the number of connections to a minimum.

Therefore, my assumption was that Nginx is where the Keepalive has to be on, and set to a bigger value, in my case "keepalive_timeout 600";

It then hits Haproxy on a local port, with the "httpclose" option on for the Apache backend:

> **option httpclose**
>     Enable or disable passive HTTP connection closing
>
> HAProxy does not yet support the HTTP keep-alive
>     mode. So by default, if a client communicates with a server in this mode, it
>     will only analyze, log, and process the first request of each connection. To
>     workaround this limitation, it is possible to specify "option httpclose". It
>     will check if a "Connection: close" header is already set in each direction,
>     and will add one if missing. Each end should react to this by actively
>     closing the TCP connection after each transfer, thus resulting in a switch to
>     the HTTP close mode. Any "Connection" header different from "close" will also
>     be removed.
>
> This option may be set both in a frontend and in a backend. It is enabled if
>     at least one of the frontend or backend holding a connection has it enabled.

Haproxy then routes connections to Apache2.

So, my assumption is that in this case I will have to turn Apache's keepalive off, since a) Nginx aggregates connections b) Haproxy closes them.

Am I correct in my reasoning and what would be a better way to optimize for keepalive in a chain like this one?

**Update:** [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/426726/do-http-reverse-proxies-typically-enable-http-keep-alive-on-the-client-side-of-t) ServerFault topic notes that it is more beneficial to remove keepalive from Haproxy as well (and thus get rid of httpclose, I presume), as the latency between Haproxy and Apache would be too low to justify removing the handshake anyway.

So that leaves us with **Nginx (KA) -> Haproxy (no KA) -> Apache (no KA)**

Is that a better option?